# How to create a tag synonym?

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms

I think I found a good tag synonym, so how should I create it? Do you have to be a mod to create it? Please tell me quick, since I might forget it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tag synonym system doesn't really scale down to sites as small as ELL.  If you'd like to propose a tag synonym, I suggest creating a meta thread to discuss it.  If everyone agrees, a mod can create it for you.

Eventually, if the site gets bigger, the system for suggesting tag synonyms may be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the [Create Tag Synonyms](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) privilege to propose tag synonyms. If you think a synonym is necessary, you can post it here, and someone with the required reputation can propose/add it.